# code::blocks on Xenial Beta

Tags: apt, dependencies, 16.04, code-blocks

Attempting to install code::blocks through the PPA with apt-get and not having much luck. I keep receiving these errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
libcodeblocks0 : Depends: libwxbase2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1+dfsg2) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1+dfsg2) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: codeblocks but it is not going to be installed
```

I have also attempted installing through Synaptic but to no avail. Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What PPA is this?

Comment: @ThomasW. Final freeze is next week, and this is answerable. I see no reason to close it.

Comment: The PPA is http://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Code::Blocks installing you have to get a bit creative, as first download the packages for Ubuntu 15.10 from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com) (simply do a search for `libwxgtk2.8-`). For a 64-bit system you can as well use the following links to download the packages. Best do the now stated commands in a separate directory so you not install any other downloads you maybe did before.

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets2.8/libwxgtk2.8-0_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets2.8/libwxgtk2.8-dbg_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets2.8/libwxgtk2.8-dev_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets2.8/libwxbase2.8-dbg_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets2.8/wx2.8-headers_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Now you can go and install those by:

```
dpkg -i wx2.8-headers_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libwxgtk2.8-0_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libwxbase2.8-dbg_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libwxgtk2.8-dbg_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libwxgtk2.8-dev_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

This is either a bug in the Ubuntu packaging (my guess) or a bug in code::blocks. The debian people build against wxWidgets 3.0 though, so I'm going with bug in the ubuntu packaging. I recommend [contacting the owner of the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+contactuser) and pointing out the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Do this

```
sudo apt-get install libwxbase2.8-dev   libwxgtk2.8-dev
```

to install the upstream packages ... then do the code::blocks install

Comment: These packages do not exist in Xenial, so this will not work.

Comment: @Seth  I am on Xenial and it works

Comment: According to http://packages.ubuntu.com neither of those packages is in Xenial, so it can't work without some kind of outside source.

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried that and it doesn't work, but thanks for the suggestion anyway

Comment: what was the error message ?